# os.path python module not working in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-templates

I am building a django app on heroku and facing a lot of trouble with `os.path` module. My project is unable to find the `templates` on heroku while its working perfectly on localhost.

This is my project hierarchy (in brief):

```
project/
        project/
               settings.py
               urls.py
               views.py
               ..
        manage.py
        templates/
                 css/
                 media/
                 Templates/
                          home.html
```

So, I used `os.path` to add the template dir in settings.py.

```
currDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
templateDir = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.split(currDir)[0], "templates"), "templates")
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    templateDir,

)
```

This is working perfectly on my localhost but not working on Heroku.

The following is mentioned on heroku (running on heroku)

> **Django tried loading these templates, in this order:**
>
> *Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:*
>
> ```
> /app/templates/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
> ```
>
> *Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:*
>
> ```
> /app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/home.html(File does not exist)
> ```

Comment: why do you have css and media in your templates folder?

Comment: @ArgsKwargs its not in folder that contains templates. its just in folder whose name is "Templates".. I know its little confusing.

Comment: @ArgsKwargs I don't think it should bother in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the small difference between Windows & *inx systems is, file naming.
`Windows, winDows, windows, windowS` represents the same file under windows but not in Linux.

This is the problem I faced with Heroku (probably, its on *inx). So, I had to use exact folder names in TEMPLATE_DIRS.

this is the correct.

```
templateDir = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.split(currDir)[0], "templates"), "Templates")
```

the previous one is:

```
templateDir = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.split(currDir)[0], "templates"), "templates")
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically os.path will be pointing to "project/project" because that's where settings.py is located. Try moving your "templates" directory there. It worked for me!

Just make sure to change templateDir to the following:

```
    templateDir = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(templateDir, "templates"),
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following worked for me on similar Heroku/MEDIA_ROOT issue.

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "project/templates/templates"), 
)
```

However, if you stuck to the default directory structure for Django, you would not have to set TEMPLATE_DIRS at all. Ie, `home.html` should be at `project/project/templates`. Typically css/javascript is [outside that directory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/). I can verify that this works on Heroku.